# assign shapes to nodes programmatically in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to assign a shape based on node values. My code is something like:

```
// some variables from the UI
var anodezoom = d3.select("#nodezoom").property("value");
var asize = d3.select("#ona").property("value");
var acolor = d3.select("#color").property("value");
var ameasure = d3.select("#shape").property("value");
// build, resize, recolor and reshape the nodes
nodes = svg.selectAll('.node')
   .data(graph.nodes.filter(function (d) {
       return d.degree > 0;
   }))
   .enter()
   .append(function (d) {
       shaping(ameasure, d);
   })
   .attr('class', 'node')
   .attr('r', function (d) {
       return resizing(anodezoom, asize, d);
   })
   .style('fill', function (d) {
       return coloring(acolor, d);
   })
   .style('stroke', function (d) {
       return coloring(acolor, d);
   })
   .call(force.drag);
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node
```

and this happens because I fail in returning a node object in the shaping function, which is:

```
function shaping(ashape, anode) {
    var shape = null;
    if (ashape === "gender") {
        if (anode.gender === "M") {
            shape = d3.svg.symbolTypes[0];
        } else if (anode.gender === "F") {
            shape = d3.svg.symbolTypes[1];
        } else {
            shape = d3.svg.symbolTypes[2];
        }
    return shape;
 };
```

I basically return a string, which to me sounded good since it's legit to do:

```
.append('circle')
```

but it's not working, so is there a way to return a Node object with the correct shape assigned in my shaping() function?

**EDIT**

I have changed my code to:

```
nodes = svg.selectAll('path')
                    .data(graph.nodes.filter(function (d) {
                        return d.degree > 0;
                    }))
                    .enter()
                    .append('path')
                    .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type(function (d) {
                        return shaping(ashape, d);
                    }))
                    .attr('class', 'node')
                    .attr('r', function (d) {
                        return resizing(anodezoom, asize, d);
                    })
                    .style('fill', function (d) {
                        return coloring(acolor, d);
                    })
                    .style('stroke', function (d) {
                        return coloring(acolor, d);
                    })
                    .call(force.drag);
```

but while the links are displayed as expected, all the nodes are in the upper left corner, barely visible... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a path, not a d3 shape, when setting the path data, then you specify the shape:

```
.append('path')
.attr('d', function(d) { return d3.symbol().type( /* shape */ ) });
```

Here is a simple example using an ordinal scale of shapes (`var shape = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.symbols);`):

```
 .append('path')   
 .attr("d", d3.symbol().type( function(d) { return shape(d.group);} ) )
```

It is implemented in this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/24a5ddaab5e2756fbc029dccc1da3f8b). This answer is with d3v4, the d3v3 code will be a little different. Code for both is compared in a minimal example below:

d3v3:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg');

svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(d3.range(6))
  .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate('+(i * 30 + 30) + ',20)'; })
    .attr('d',d3.svg.symbol()
                .type(function(d,i){ return d3.svg.symbolTypes[i]; })
                .size(function(d,i){ return i * 30 + 30; })
         )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

d3v4:

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',400).attr('height',200);

svg.selectAll('.symbol')
   .data(d3.range(6))
   .enter()
   .append('path')
   .attr('transform',function(d,i) { return 'translate('+(i*30+30)+','+30+')';})
   .attr('d',d3.symbol()
           .type(function(d,i){ return d3.symbols[i];})
           .size(function(d,i){ return i * 30 + 30; })
   )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: while I think you put me on the right track, please have a look at my edited question if you have a sec

Comment: You'll need to apply a transform on the symbol paths to place them properly, see the above snippets. And for size, instead of r, you'll need to use `.size` on the symbol itself, I've edited the answer to include a size parameter in both the snippets.

Comment: the transform thing is not clear to me, right now I am assigning them positions according to my tick() function, but what is the default position for the force layout?

Comment: When they are the symbols are zero zero, they are in the top left corner. The symbol path is centered on a zero zero coordinate. You'll need to use a transform to position it. The [bl.ock.org](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/24a5ddaab5e2756fbc029dccc1da3f8b) example referenced in the answer, is a force layout and the tick function updates the transform rather than the cx,cx properties of a circle. The starting position can be assigned the same way - but it only lasts a tick.

Comment: ok cool now I see the correct shapes, but the links seem to be displayed incorrectly, should I transform also for them instead of set the attributes for x1, x2, y1, and y2?

Comment: That's odd, the links should be fine with x1 through y2 - the elements are updated by the nodes in the force, so if you update the symbols it doesn't have any effect on the links. Is it possible to see the whole code?